# PWA Workbox Wizard is stopping after the first step

Tags: single-page-application, service-worker, wizard, workbox, progressive-web-apps

I am setting up a PWA and trying to add a Service Worker using Work Box. When I type 'Workbox Wizard' in to the terminal, only the first question about the root file is being asked and then the terminal freezes and I can't type anything else. Please help!

Comment: Can you clarify how this is related to programming? Maybe you want to contact the creator of that PWA?

Comment: Could you post on https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/new, and we can follow up there?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Trying to debug...